# Aggregate several pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

second beginner question of the day.

I have a list of identifiers stored in a list. Let’s say, as an example that:

```
ID = [100, 101, 102, 103, … 200]
```

I have then several excel files saved inside a specific folder. These files are organized as follows:

```
Name of the file: April 2021

ID  Name    Color
105 Bob     Red
158 Jean    Blue

Name of the file: May 2021:

ID  Name    Color
110 Bob     Green
158 Jean    Yellow
```

The thing is, not all the IDs from the first list are present in the excel files.

My end goal, is to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  Apr 2021    May 2021
100    -           -
105   Red          -
110             Yellow
158   Blue      Yellow
```

I’m familiar with the methods to loop through all the files in a folder. I am also able to find all the identifiers that are located in the excel files, and to return in which file they are located.

However, I’m struggling to return the data associated with the identifiers, not the identifiers themselves. I am also struggling to aggregate the data coming from the different files into the same dataframe (pandas says he can’t create a dataframe when the size of the arrays are different in size).

I hope that my question is clear, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:
Create a dataframe with all your ID (List you provided above). And left join using pd.merge with the dataframe you would create from the individual files on the ID.

Comment: Thanks, after some research with pd.merge , I found the solution I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

First Transpose ID by transpose() function --> `ID.T`
Secondly `frames = [ID, color1, color2]` where `color1` and `color2` denotes the dataframe from the file of the respective month.
Thirdly `result = pd.concat(frames, keys=["ID", "April2021", "May2021"])`